# How to do bulk insert In mariadb using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mariadb, mariasql

Whenever i am trying to run my code this is showing the column count doesn't match error.

```
values=[
    [{id:12227722345,name:"dgssssdavgsgfv",pass:"cvhsssssadfvugod"}],
    [{id:12,name:"ddd",pass:"cvh"}]
   ];

c.query('insert into Hash.asn(userid,username,password) values (?,?,?)',[values],function(err,rows)
{
  if (err)
    console.log(err);

  c.query('commit');
  console.log(rows);

});
```

Error:

```
{ [Error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1] code: 1136 }
```

Comment: I am not sure but just suggestion try with one value maybe the [] format is causing issue.

Comment: One value is working but i want to do with multiple value So can you help me how to do it?

Comment: just suggestion if its help. as i also not tried, why u keeping [] around the {} object ? any reason. if u remove it and try.

Comment: Then how will you send multiple values Like multiple id,multiple username at a time .

Comment: I think something like this - var values = [{1,'a','b'}, {2,'v','h'}];  insert into Hash.asn(userid,username,password) values (?,?,?)',[values]

Comment: i have tried this also but its showing the same error

Comment: if u still struggling with this -once try this way      --   insert into Hash.asn(userid,username,password) values (?,?,?)',[(1,'a','b'),(2,'v','h')]

Comment: Its not takeing the 2nd value .I have solve this problem for static data but i am not able to insert dynamic data .

Comment: i guess then ur dynamic data format need to be similar like ur static data. something is not matching data format.

Comment: may be..let me try .if i face any difficulties then i will comment here

Answer (score 9):

In case anyone is still wondering this you can use connection.batch() to perform bulk queries.

```
connection.beginTransaction();
connection.query("INSERT INTO BASKET(customerId) values (?)", [1], (err, res) => {
   //must handle error if any
   const basketId = res.insertId;
   try {
     connection.batch("INSERT INTO basket_item(basketId, itemId) VALUES (?, ?)",[
         [basketId, 100],
         [basketId, 101],
         [basketId, 103],
         [basketId, 104],
         [basketId, 105]
     ]);
     //must handle error if any
     connection.commit();
     } catch (err) {
     connection.rollback();
     //handle error
     }
});
```

https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-connector-nodejs/blob/master/documentation/batch.md

Comment: this answer is premium

Answer (score -1):

These days, As I know it, mariaDB module was not support bulk insert on the node.js.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/connectornodejs-pipelining/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.